# Spring data redis key expiration

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis

In spring data redis we have two variables.

```
RedisTemplate<Key, Value> redisTemplate;
```

```
HashOperations<Key, HashKey, HashValue> hashOperations;
```

There is a method expireAt(String key, Date date) inside RedisTemplate. So if I want to set an expiry for a particular hash key I can use this method or this only works at Key level and expires all the entries inside that key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it helps anyone, I am using redisTemplate.expireAt(String Key, Date date) method for this purpose. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Redis (and also Spring Data Redis) you can only use `EXPIRE` (which is what `expireAt(String key, Date date)` uses) on an entire key - you cannot expire some fields (entries) of a `hash` but not others. You can only expire the entire `hash`.

This means if you want to expire some `hash` fields but not others you'll need to find a workaround. One that I've used before is to have a second `hash` (or a `zset`) with the same fields as my `hash`, but where the value of each field (score if using a `zset`) is the timestamp at which the field should expire. The drawback here is that you'll need to have some code to check when fields expire and then remove them.

Another option would be to just use regular `string` keys instead of a `hash`. But that comes with its own drawbacks (e.g. if you need `HLEN` you'll need to implement that in your code using `SCAN`).